# Using `car` to recode across range of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I've been poking about on the internet, and can't figure out how to apply `car` to recode values for a range of columns.

To recode values for a single column, I'd run a command such as:

```
 df$dv_r <- recode(df$dv, "2=1;1=0;0=NA")
```

And then if I wanted to do this for the whole data.frame, I could run:

```
 df_2 <- lapply(df, FUN = function(x) recode(x, "2=1;1=0;0=NA"))
```

However, I'm not sure how to do this for a range of columns -- for example, in a hypothetical `data.table` called `df`, how would I recode values for columns ranging from `20:40`?

Thanks! Sure this is super easy for R experts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps there is a more `data.table` way to do this, but here is one possibility:

```
library(data.table)
library(car)

## Here is some sample data
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(A = sample(0:2, 10, replace = TRUE), 
                 B = sample(0:2, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 C = sample(0:2, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 D = rnorm(10), E = rnorm(10), ID = 1:10)
dt
#     A B C           D           E ID
#  1: 0 0 2 -0.04493361 -0.05612874  1
#  2: 1 0 0 -0.01619026 -0.15579551  2
#  3: 1 2 1  0.94383621 -1.47075238  3
#  4: 2 1 0  0.82122120 -0.47815006  4
#  5: 0 2 0  0.59390132  0.41794156  5
#  6: 2 1 1  0.91897737  1.35867955  6
#  7: 2 2 0  0.78213630 -0.10278773  7
#  8: 1 2 1  0.07456498  0.38767161  8
#  9: 1 1 2 -1.98935170 -0.05380504  9
# 10: 0 2 1  0.61982575 -1.37705956 10
```

Use `.SDcols` to define which columns you want to apply the function to.

```
dt[, 1:3 := lapply(.SD, recode, "2=1;1=0;0=NA"), .SDcols = 1:3]
dt
#      A  B  C           D           E ID
#  1: NA NA  1 -0.04493361 -0.05612874  1
#  2:  0 NA NA -0.01619026 -0.15579551  2
#  3:  0  1  0  0.94383621 -1.47075238  3
#  4:  1  0 NA  0.82122120 -0.47815006  4
#  5: NA  1 NA  0.59390132  0.41794156  5
#  6:  1  0  0  0.91897737  1.35867955  6
#  7:  1  1 NA  0.78213630 -0.10278773  7
#  8:  0  1  0  0.07456498  0.38767161  8
#  9:  0  0  1 -1.98935170 -0.05380504  9
# 10: NA  1  0  0.61982575 -1.37705956 10
```

Comment: And if I want to use variable names instead of column numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. In fact doing only on a subset of the data.frame lets you avoid having to redo the data.frame call:

```
  df_2[ , col_names]  <- lapply(df[ ,colnames] , 
                                FUN = function(x) recode(x, "2=1;1=0;0=NA"))
```

Of do it by col-number:

```
  df_2[ , 20:40]  <- lapply(df[ ,20:40] , 
                                FUN = function(x) recode(x, "2=1;1=0;0=NA"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you add a quick explanation for why this doesn't work in data.table?  I had to reconvert to data.frame to make it work, and further knowledge of why this is the case would be awesome :)

Comment: `[<-.data.table` syntax is completely different from `[<-.data.frame` syntax. I didn't notice that data.table was part of the question. If you post a test case in the future you will get better answers.

Comment: for data frames you would do it like   library(dplyr)
df_2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df , FUN = function(x) dplyr::recode(x, "2"="1","1"="0","0"="NA")))

Answer (score 1):

Using variable names instead of column numbers would be something like:

```
cnames <- c("A", "B", "C")    
dt[ , (cnames) := lapply(.SD, recode, "2=1;1=0;0=NA"), .SDcols = cnames]
```